# gitlab vagrant vm rake:test aborted

Tags: rake, virtualbox, vagrant, gitlab

i'm trying to install the `gitlab-vagrant-vm` from these repository: `https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-vagrant-vm`

if i'm running
`bundle exec rake gitlab:test` it runs the test with all it's cases and checks.
but the summary gives me following lines of error.

```
Error summary:
  Errors (1)
    Project Issue Tracker :: I set the issue tracker to "Redmine" :: And change the issue tracker to "Redmine"


Steps Summary: (1379) Successful, (0) Undefined, (0) Pending, (0) Failed, (1) Error

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /vagrant/gitlabhq/coverage. 4937 / 7059 LOC (69.94%) covered.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/opt/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -S...]

Tasks: TOP => spinach
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
rake spinach failed!
/vagrant/gitlabhq/lib/tasks/gitlab/test.rake:15:in `block (3 levels) in '
/vagrant/gitlabhq/lib/tasks/gitlab/test.rake:12:in `each'
/vagrant/gitlabhq/lib/tasks/gitlab/test.rake:12:in `block (2 levels) in '
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/gitlabhq$
```

what's this error about, and how to fix it? i really want to work with gitlab, and trying for several days now...

i am using:
osx 10.9 with server 3
vagrant 1.3.5
virtualbox 4.3
in the vagrant vm i ran "apt-get update / upgrade" to get the latest ubuntu

greetz!